# Extra space between content and footer

Tags: css, html, spacing

I set up a sticky footer at [my site](http://gsingh93.github.com/) using [this method](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), and for some reason there's a large amount of extra space between the bottom of the content and the top of the footer. I can't figure out why. Since there's not much content on the first page, the page shouldn't even extend beyond the viewport and there shouldn't be scrollbars. What's going on?

Here's the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/pygment_trac.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title>gulshansingh.com</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="/images/banner.jpg">
    </header>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
    <li><a href='/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/about/'><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/projects/'><span>Projects</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/articles/'><span>Articles</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <section id="main_content">
    <h3>Welcome to GitHub Pages.</h3>

<p>This is a test home page for my site</p>

<pre><code>$ cd your_repo_root/repo_name
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout gh-pages
</code></pre>

<h3>Section 2</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

      </section>
      <div class="push">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      Footer content goes here
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS (Although looking at Firebug/CDT might be more helpful):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

#footer, .push {
    height: 80px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #161616;
  color: #eaeaea;
  font: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Terminal, monospace;
}

/* General & 'Reset' Stuff */

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 15px 0 5px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.4 ;
}

header, header img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #469B46;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #469B46;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #469B46;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #469B46;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #469B46;
}

#downloads .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Main Content
*/

#main_content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #474747;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
section img {
  max-width: 100%
}

h1, h1 a, h2, h2 a, h3, h3 a, h4, h4 a, h5, h5 a, h6, h6 a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Terminal, monospace;
  color: #b5e853;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(181, 232, 83, 0.1),
               0 0 10px rgba(181, 232, 83, 0.1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* FF3.7+ */
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}

h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}

#main_content h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#main_content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#main_content h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#main_content h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main_content h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#main_content h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

dt {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: ">>";
  font-family: Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Terminal, monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #b5e853;
  margin-left: -37px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  line-height: 16px;
}*/

blockquote {
  color: #aaa;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px dotted #666;
}

pre {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #b5e853;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  text-wrap: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #b5e853;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

hr {
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #b5e853;
  color: #b5e853;
}

/* Buttons
*/

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.3), rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.3) 50%, rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.6), rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.6) 50%, rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.btn .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 1px 8px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.btn-github .icon {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: url("../images/blacktocat.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

/* Links
   a, a:hover, a:visited
*/

a {
  color: #63c0f5;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(104, 182, 255, 0.5);
}

/* Clearfix */

.cf:before, .cf:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear:both;
}

.cf {
  zoom:1;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid #15893d;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #0c0c0c;
    line-height: 80px;
}

#footer_inner {
    display: table-cell;
}

#footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eaeaea;
}

#footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: I've had this problem before, have you tried putting all of the page in a wrapper div? That was how i solved it

Comment: @AdamBrown That almost works, the extra space is gone, but the div is a few pixels less than the body for some reason (which means the footer is not exactly at the bottom), and setting height to 100% makes the extra space come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.container` element should wrap around all the other elements in the body except for the footer. This means you have to place the header in the `.container` element as well, because it's height of 100% means it will take up the height of the viewport. Since your header/navigation has been excluded from the `.container` element, the viewport height will be extended down further by the height of the header.

And please consider posting your example in a fiddle instead of your site, or any other external site that makes it too localized and less relevant to the rest of the SO community.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the page is still a pixel over the viewport size, but it's not a problem (just strange). And next time I'll use a fiddle.

Comment: That's because you have a 2px top border on the footer element, so your margin offset on the container should be -82px instead.